# Swift 4- How to use two viewControllers with one Xib file?

Tags: swift

Can we use one xib file for two view controllers?

Comment: you can simply load same xib in both viewControllers. Actually that's what a xib is used for bro. Reusability.

Comment: How can I do that? I am searching that, but do not know what is the procedure?

Comment: what is the xib for?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. Xib is for one of my screen. The same screen is used by a view controller and I want to use it in an another view controller.

Comment: can you add the picture of your xib

Comment: `self.navigationController!.pushViewController(MyViewController(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: nil), animated: true)` . remember instead of MyViewController you have to use name of your class you have assigned to your XIB and also in nibName

Comment: do this wherever you are trying to open both viewControllers

Comment: Not working, the buttons are not getting attached to a the new View controller with your code.

Comment: add the code where you are using the above line and the code of your xib class file

Comment: The xib file is not in code. It is in view. Should I add it from the Xib source code?

Comment: where did you take the outlets of the views in xib ?

Comment: To the first view controller.

Comment: have you ever created tableViewCell using xib

Answer (score 0):

**Common XIB**

```
import UIKit

//MARK:- ConfirmationView
/**
 This Class is used to show a common View for limited time
 */
class ConfirmationView: UIView
{
    //MARK: UIView
    /// Main Content View
    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

    //MARK: UILabel
    /// Title to display in View
    @IBOutlet weak var headerLabel: UILabel!

    //MARK: Init Class
    /**
     This function is used to Initialise the class
     */
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        loadNib()
    }

    //MARK: Encoder
    /**
     This function is used to Store the class objects added
     */
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        loadNib()
    }

    //MARK: Dienit class
    /**
     This function is used to De-Allocate the class objects
     */
    deinit {
        /// Remove all The Initiated Instances
    }
}

//MARK:- Required Functions
extension ConfirmationView
{
    //MARK: Load Nib
    /**
     This function is used to load the Nib from Bundle
     */
    func loadNib() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ConfirmationView", owner: self, options: [:])
        // 2. Adding the 'contentView' to self (self represents the instance of a WeatherView which is a 'UIView').
        addSubview(contentView)
        // 3. Setting this false allows us to set our constraints on the contentView programtically
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        // 4. Setting the constraints programatically
        contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Need to set its size

[image]

[image]

**Usage**

in Main Controller

```
///Create a Reference for XIB

/// Confirmation View Xib Class Reference
private var confirmationViewXib : ConfirmationView?
```

Usage To add in ViewController as Subview

```
confirmationViewXib = self.showConfirmationView(staticText: "Sign Up Completed using \(loginType)")
self.view.addSubview(confirmationViewXib!)
```

Showing Method

```
//MARK: Show ConfirmatonView
/**
  This function is used show the confirmationView Xib with text Passing
 */
func showConfirmationView(staticText:String) -> ConfirmationView
{
    let newView = ConfirmationView.init(frame: self.view.bounds)
    newView.headerLabel.text = staticText
    return newView        
}
```

Note : Implement Delegates or observer to take output from XIB in Main Controller